# What is exactly an electric field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-circuits, electric-fields

I saw in video lectures of Walter lewin on electricity and magnetism that the electric field at a point in space is force that a test positive charge experiences at that point due to presence of some other charge. That definition was quite intuitive too. But  i also read that when a conductor is connected to a battery they all start moving in a certain direction due to presence of an electric field opposite to flow of electrons. Now I don't see why that happens. I mean that why does a conductor connected with a battery produces an electric field opposite to it?

Answer (score 0):

A conductor is just a pipeline for **negatively charged** electrons. Positively charged particles (like ions in electrolytes) flow in the field direction.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean that why does a conductor connected with a battery produces an
> electric field opposite to it?

Connecting the conductor to the battery terminals doesn't produce an electric field. The electric field is produced by the battery and exists in the air between the terminals without the conductor connected.

The reason no current flows between the terminals without a conductor connected to them is that the electrical resistivity of air (roughly 2 x 10$^{16}$ $\Omega$.m) is so high the force exerted by the field on electrons in the air is not sufficient to break them free from the protons in order for current to flow.

But once a conductor is connected between the terminals, the force exerted by the same field is sufficient to cause the mobile electrons in the conductor to flow in the direction opposite to the direction of the field.

Hope this helps.